# How do I, programmatically and from inside of a macro, obtain the fully rendered version of a page the macro is included in?

Tags: python, macros, moinmoin

I'm looking to write a moinmoin macro which performs some processing on the fully rendered version of a page (maybe this is best achieved with an action instead? I'm new to moinmoin and uncertain of the best approach).

Is there an easy way for me to obtain the fully rendered version of the moinmoin page the macro is included in?

It seems the request object has some properties which are close (such as page and data), but not the final results

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

I can't think of any macro language that allows you to do this, and in fact, I can't see how it would be even possible to do, as it would trigger infinite recursion. Neither can I see any reason to do it.

If you want to process the fully rendered page, you need to do that after the page has been rendered, not from inside a macro. I don't know which the best way to do that with MoinMoin is. Perhaps a WSGI middleware, assuming you run it with WSGI.

It also depends on what processing you want to do. [Diazo](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/) is a pretty awesome way to skin sites for example.